# AtTask API - 401 Unauthorized error on report

Tags: attask

When I try to GET a report (as shown on this page: https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#Report), but I keep getting a 401: Unauthorized error. I know the URL is fine, because when I copy and paste into the address bar exactly what my code is spitting out, it returns results. Here's an example URL that I'm trying to use:

https://webmdhs.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/cmpy/report?ID_GroupBy=true&name_GroupBy=false

I'm giving the API the same username and password that I used when I logged into the AtTask GUI and successfully ran the report from the address bar, so I know that user is authorized to run reports. Any idea why I'm getting a 401 error?

Comment: `...what my code is spitting out...` Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I misread the documentation about SessionID. I thought you didn't have to include it in the URI for GET requests, but that's only if you put the request into the *address bar*. All I had to do was add the SessionID and it worked just fine.